# How to access a value in a list and use it with python in this case?

Tags: python, arrays, list

For example I have a list and the user will input interger values,
And I want to use this numbers if they are bigger than another number so I can do operations with the specific number.Here's what I tried:

```
list=[]
NUM=10
summ=0
count10=0
for i in range(NUM):
    list.append(int(input("Type a number: ")))  
    if list>10:
        count10+=1
        summ=summ+list  #(when number bigger than ten for     example)
        m=summ/count10
    print(m)
```

Comment: Try to avoid keywords like `list` as variable names.

Comment: List is just to illustrate the problem that I have.

Comment: `L` is way better than `list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if list[i]>10:
       count10+=1
       summ=summ+=list[i]
       m=summ/count10
```

Put this in your loop, you acces the element in position i of the list with `list[i]`